# Powershell to select maximum date from XML

Tags: xml, powershell

I am extracting data from an XML file using PowerShell, successfully in that I can getting the field values I want only, as per the attached part of a script. From the returned values of a long list of dates, I want the latest of those dates ONLY.

What can I succeed the attached code with to move on and get the only value I want?

```
$DS.ReadXml($DBPaht,[System.Data.XmlReadMode]::Auto);
$DS.Tables["LearningDelivery"].("LearnStartDate");
```

Comment: `$DS.Tables["LearningDelivery"].("LearnStartDate") | Get-Date | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Last 1`

Answer (score 0):

So if you only want the last couple of objects in your table you could pipe it to:

`| Select-Object -Last 5` where you replace the 5 with however many of few you would like.

Basically your data in your tables should be an array, piping to the select and choosing last will output only the last objects in your array.

**Edit**
To get the first occurrence you can use the -First switch instead, so:
`| Select-Object -First 5`

Comment: Thanks for coming back, Henrik. It's not really the last value I need in terms of the list order, it's the actually the earliest (I meant earliest rather than latest in my original post.) date that I need.

Comment: I updated my answer, instead of -Last you can use -First to get only the first x objects in your array :)